# Iterating random number within For loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, random, callback

I'm attempting to use a For loop to add a random integer (from 0-2) to a variable a specified amount of times. The problem I'm having is that the loop isn't using a new random number every time it loops, so I'm only getting either 0, 9, or 18 if I pass in 9 for example.

I am expecting an object to return with keys "a" and "b" having different number values.

Here's my random number getter:

```
function randomNumber(min, max){
   min = Math.ceil(0);
   max = Math.floor(3);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

and here's the function where I call randomNumber():

```
function objMaker(cb, num){
  let obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    obj.a += cb;
    obj.b += cb;
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```
objMaker(randomNumber(), 9)
// returns obj { a:0, b:0}
// or obj { a:9, b:9}
// or obj { a:18, b:18}
```

I'm a beginner so I appreciate the help as I have not been able to find anything on the matter. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to generate a new random number at *every iteration* of the `for` loop. If it's the case, then you need to call your `randomNumber()` at every iteration too:

```js
function randomNumber() {
   const min = Math.ceil(0);
   const max = Math.floor(3);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function objMaker(num){
  let obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    obj.a += randomNumber();
    obj.b += randomNumber();
  }
  return obj;
}

function test() {
  console.log(objMaker(9));
}
```

```html
<button id=generate onclick='test()'>generate</button>
```

If you write `objMaker(randomNumber(), 9)` then it generates 0, 1 or 2 once and then passes it as `cb` to the `objMaker`. So inside the `for` loop it always adds the same number 9 times.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Makes total sense now.

Answer (score 0):

So what you did was: you passed the ***result of*** `randomNumber()` to the `objMaker` function's first parameter. Here I emphasize on 'result of', because that means that your `cb` argument inside the `randomNumber` function is a number, meaning that it does not change inside your function.

```js
function randomNumber(min, max){
   min = Math.ceil(0);
   max = Math.floor(3);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function objMaker(cb, num){
  console.log(cb); // notice that this is a number
  let obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {

    // cb is both same since a number was passed (not a function)
    obj.a += cb; 
    obj.b += cb; // both cb here are identical, so a and b is the same at the end
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(objMaker(randomNumber(), 9)) // randomNumber() here returns a random value
```

To be honest, I personally don't understand why you have to pass the `randomNumber` function to the `objMaker`, but assuming that you need to, I think the best way here is to pass the `randomNumber` ***function***, instead of the result of `randomNumber()`.

```js
function randomNumber(min, max){
   min = Math.ceil(0);
   max = Math.floor(3);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function objMaker(cb, num){
  let obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    obj.a += cb();
    obj.b += cb();
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(objMaker(randomNumber, 9))
```

Or based on your usage, you can have different but constant terms of cb for a and b.

```js
function randomNumber(min, max){
   min = Math.ceil(0);
   max = Math.floor(3);
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function objMaker(cb, cb2, num){
  let obj = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    obj.a += cb;
    obj.b += cb2;
  }
  return obj;
}

console.log(objMaker(randomNumber(), randomNumber(), 9))
```

Comment: Wow that makes a lot of sense, I must've been really tunnel visioned to miss that. I appreciate the multiple solutions. And yes, I am trying to comprehend the effects of callback functions so I did need to have a separate function for randomNumber() for the sake of learning.

Comment: No problem. Enjoy :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using 0 or 1 as min value, it isnt necessary to specify that(specifying max alone is enough). The below function would work assuming max is 2

```
function randomNumber(max){
   return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
}
```

Hope this helps.